# ASP.NET MVC 3 connection to secure remote WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, authentication

I am new to all the web thing so the question may seem trivial but not to me. The implementation logic is:

ASP.NET MVC 3 -> WCF Service -> SQL Database

Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET MVC3 use custom Membership and Role providers because all the log in details are stored in SQL Database.
There is a requirement to implement authorization to WCF service too. That uses the same credentials as ASP.NET MVC 3. 
I have implemented Username type for WCF security using custom UsernameValidator.

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
</security>
```

It works for the first time, when user logs in to the web site because there are credentials. However, after FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie on ASP.NET MVC 3, the user name is all I have. 
As MVC approach consists of variety of controllers, I have to create instance of WCF client on each and every of them. But without credentials it does not make sense.

```
       [Authorize]
        public class MyController : Controller
        {
            private WebServiceClient ServiceClient = new WebServiceClient();

            public ActionResult Index(string userName)
            {
              var model = ServiceClient.GetDataList();
              return View(model);
            }
        }
```

The new instance does not use existing session. It creates a new one with blank credentials.

- Is there a secure way of creating instance of WCF client per session?
- Or an option of WCF accepting ASP.NET authentication?
- What is the       best way of attaching asp.net authentication to wcf
  request?

Comment: Have a look at this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460435/asp-net-to-wcf-passthrough-security and even better this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451578/wcf-authentication-using-sql-membership-provider

Comment: Thank you for the links. The first one was very useful.

Comment: Nice one. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [the suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460435/asp-net-to-wcf-passthrough-security) it was decided to keep ASP.NET MVC server and WCF service on one machine and use net.pipe endpoint for communication. Thank you.